# Getting text from HTML using BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to do a real estate scraper to search for apartments. The desired output is:

Condomínio R$ 980

and I'm getting this:
`[<div class="info-right text-xs-right"><p><span class="h-money">Condomínio R$ 980</span></p></div>]`

How can I extract this text from the span tag?

The webscraper code is this one:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
import itertools
import time

def main():
    
    list_price = []
    list_info_extra = []
    list_descrip = []
    list_url = []

    #Connection and cursor creation
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="guilherme", passwd="fadel_gui", database="dawn18")
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    if mydb.cursor:
        print("Connected to database")

    headers = ({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228 Safari/537.36'})

    URL = ["https://www.imobiliariapadreanchieta.com.br/imoveis/a-venda/apartamento/curitiba/bigorrilho", 
    "https://www.imobiliariapadreanchieta.com.br/imoveis/a-venda/apartamento/curitiba/bigorrilho?pagina=2", 
    "https://www.imobiliariapadreanchieta.com.br/imoveis/a-venda/apartamento/curitiba/bigorrilho?pagina=3"]

    for url in range (0, 3):
        
        response = requests.get(URL[url], headers=headers)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        text = soup.find_all(text = True)

        house_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_= "col-sm-12 col-lg-6 box-align")


        if house_containers != []:

            for container in house_containers:

                #Price information
                price = container.find_all('div', class_="info-left")[0].text


                IPTU = soup.select_one('div.info-right.text-xs-right p span.h-money').text

                info_containers = soup.find_all('div', class_="values")

                for info in info_containers:
                    get_info = info.select_one('span', class_="h-money")

                    if get_info:
                        info_apart = get_info
                    else:
                        info_apart = 'No info'

                if IPTU:
                    info_right = IPTU
                else:
                    info_right = 'No info'
            
                url_imovel = 'www.imobiliariapadreanchieta.com.br' + container.find_all('a')[0].get('href')
                
                print(price)
                print(info_apart)
                print(info_right)
                print(url_imovel)
                print('\n')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm trying to get prices, urls and information like: rooms, bathrooms, master bedrooms, etc. The URLs i'm scraping can be seen in the "URL" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the NoneType error free working example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228 Safari/537.36'}
URL = ["https://www.imobiliariapadreanchieta.com.br/imoveis/a-venda/apartamento/curitiba/bigorrilho?pagina="+str(x)+"" for x in range(1,4)]

for url in URL:

    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    for container in soup.find_all('div', class_="card card-listing"):
        price = container.find('span', class_="h-money location").text
        
        r= container.select_one('div.info-right.text-xs-right p:nth-child(1) span')
        p = r.text if r else None
        q= container.select_one('div.info-right.text-xs-right p:nth-child(2) span')
        t= q.text if q else None
        
            
        print('price:' + str(price) + ',' + 'Condomínio:' +  str(p) +',' + 'IPTU:' + str(t))  
    print("-" * 85)
```

Output:

```
price:R$ 135.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 350,IPTU:IPTU R$ 40/mês
price:R$ 160.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 300,IPTU:IPTU R$ 36/mês
price:R$ 165.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 350,IPTU:IPTU R$ 40/mês
price:R$ 180.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 350,IPTU:IPTU R$ 40/mês
price:R$ 180.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 400,IPTU:IPTU R$ 39/mês
price:R$ 265.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 625,IPTU:IPTU R$ 40/mês
price:R$ 290.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 350,IPTU:None
price:R$ 295.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 566,IPTU:IPTU R$ 536/ano
price:R$ 299.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 600,IPTU:IPTU R$ 32/mês
price:R$ 329.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 443,IPTU:None
price:R$ 390.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 565,IPTU:IPTU R$ 101/mês
price:R$ 400.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 450,IPTU:None
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
price:R$ 450.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 700,IPTU:IPTU R$ 90/mês
price:R$ 450.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 800,IPTU:IPTU R$ 100/mês  
price:R$ 465.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 480,IPTU:None
price:R$ 480.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 745,IPTU:IPTU R$ 98/mês   
price:R$ 510.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 600,IPTU:None
price:R$ 515.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 700,IPTU:IPTU R$ 100/mês  
price:R$ 575.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 850,IPTU:IPTU R$ 1.000/mês
price:R$ 590.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 600,IPTU:IPTU R$ 140/mês  
price:R$ 590.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 550,IPTU:IPTU R$ 78/mês   
price:R$ 690.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 1.080,IPTU:IPTU R$ 210/mês
price:R$ 720.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 1.000,IPTU:IPTU R$ 152/mês
price:R$ 795.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 950,IPTU:IPTU R$ 143/mês
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
price:R$ 830.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 1.020,IPTU:IPTU R$ 156/mês
price:R$ 850.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 780,IPTU:None
price:R$ 889.000,Condomínio:None,IPTU:None
price:R$ 890.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 905,IPTU:None
price:R$ 923.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 600,IPTU:None
price:R$ 990.000,Condomínio:Condomínio R$ 980,IPTU:None
price:R$ 1.000.000,Condomínio:None,IPTU:None
price:R$ 1.171.460,Condomínio:None,IPTU:None
price:R$ 1.221.000,Condomínio:None,IPTU:None
price:R$ 1.418.000,Condomínio:None,IPTU:None
-------------
```

---

Comment: Thank you so much! Just one more question. If I want to take the number of bedrooms, bathrooms, etc, how could i do it? In my code i'm currently using: `for p in container.find_all('div', class_="values"):
     p.find_all('span', class_= 'h-money')
     print(p.text)`

Comment: Thanks. No need loop again if so will get error because  each  full  container already looped at first.  Now you can  extract data whatever do you want from the container like me meaning  like: price, Condomínio  selected correct element.

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

You try to select the first value from soup in each iteration, thats why the result is always the same:

```
IPTU = soup.select_one('div.info-right.text-xs-right p span.h-money').text
```

#### How to fix?

Change `soup` into `container`:

```
IPTU = container.select_one('div.info-right.text-xs-right p span.h-money').text
```

#### EDIT

as Guilherme has mentioned, a check for the presence of the element can also be established to exclude error messages:

```
IPTU = container.select_one('div.info-right.text-xs-right p span.h-money').text if container.select_one('div.info-right.text-xs-right p span.h-money') else 'No info here'
```

Comment: This worked! But sometimes it gives me an error because some apartments don't have this information. The error is this:  ``` File "/home/guilherme/dawn-project/src.py", line 72, in main
    IPTU = container.select_one('div.info-right.text-xs-right p span.h-money').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'``` . How can i avoid this error message?

Comment: In my code and with the URLs i'm scraping this will give an error message. To avoid it I just did this: `if container.select_one('div.info-right.text-xs-right p span.h-money') == None: IPTU = 'No info here'             else: IPTU = container.select_one('div.info-right.text-xs-right p span.h-money').text print(IPTU)`

Comment: Very good that you have continued independently from here on. It is also primarily about the community answering your core question and not already serving the complete code that covers all eventualities. - Well done, that shows that you also deal with the topic.